# Lock multiple functions across azure processes

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I have two web jobs running (separately) with separate web job names, that will sometimes try and run the same function (which in turns modifies data).  I want to ensure they can't run simultaneously.   Since they are running in two different processes, I can't use the C# `lock()` mechanism.  I also can't use the `[Singleton]` attribute as they are separate web jobs with different names.

What do you recommend to handle this?  I am thinking about something like the Lease Blob operation (to a storage account) but can't get much information on doing this.

Or I guess a blocking transaction of sorts?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can use `[Singleton]` attributes on web job functions for a wide variety of purposes, including for implementing both more granular, and coarser applications.

From the [Sdk Documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Singleton#locking-across-different-functions), you can use the `SingletonScope.Host` option to share a lock between different functions, provided the given name is the same:

> **Locking Across Different Functions**
>
> In addition to using Singleton locks scoped to a single function, you can also declare locks that work across multiple functions. In this example we show two functions that can be triggered independently, but we want to ensure that only one of them runs at any given time:

```
[Singleton("ItemsLock", SingletonScope.Host)]
public static void AddItem([QueueTrigger("add-item")] string message)
{
     // Perform the add operation
}

[Singleton("ItemsLock", SingletonScope.Host)]
public static void RemoveItem([QueueTrigger("remove-item")] string message)
{
     // Perform the remove operation
}
```

Comment: AFAIK this will restrict these functions to just a [single Host](https://maximelabelle.wordpress.com/2014/04/09/performing-parallel-processing-in-azure-web-jobs/), which from a scalability perspective, would be the nett result of a distributed lock anyway.

Comment: This is a great feature.